# What is the meaning of (the perhaps swisswide used) "resonieren"

Tags: word-usage, single-word-request, german-to-english, swiss-standard-german

In the swiss german song for children [Joggeli sött go Birli schüttle](http://chinderliedli.ch/index.php/2010/09/10/joggeli-sott-go-birli-schuttle/) I came accross the word *resoniere* of which the written german equivalent should (probably) be *resonieren*.

> [...] Do goht de Meischter sälber us,
>    und foht a resonniere. [...]

I don't know what the meaning of this word is, perhaps it's of french origin. From the song's context, I'd assume that the word means something like *force somebody to do something*. Is this correct?

Comment: Thank you René for this question. I only just now looked at your link for the children's song and there was something familiar about it. Well I found this [web page](http://www.dasnorm.ch/joggeli_special/02_herkunft.html#3) and it turns out it really is the [Chad Gadya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chad_Gadya) sung at the seder. This brings back childhood memories :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The word in question is probably [räsonieren](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/raesonieren):

> 1. (bildungssprachlich) sich wortreich äußern, sich [überflüssigerweise] über etwas auslassen
> 2. (umgangssprachlich) seinem Unmut, seiner Unzufriedenheit durch [ständiges] Schimpfen Ausdruck geben
> 3. (veraltet) vernünftig reden, Schlüsse ziehen <sup>Duden</sup>

This means: *to make wordy explanations, to argue, to rant, to draw conclusions*.

The Swiss dictionary [Schweizerischen Idiotikon](http://www.idiotikon.ch/) lists another meaning that is close to the French origin [raisonneé](http://dict.leo.org/frde?lp=frde&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=raisonnee) *"to give thought to something"*:

[image]

Comment: `To reason` scheint mir auch oft nicht nur passend, sondern auch vom gleichen Stamm.

Answer (score 0):

The English translation I have used  in the past is "resonate."

EDIT: I have been advised by someone whose opinion I respect that this was a "nice guess, you tried to help, nothing wrong with that, but this is a wrong answer."

I now believe that "räsonieren," as in Takkat's answer, is a more reasonable rendering of resoniere than resonieren, given the context. Accordingly, a better translation might be to scold or to rant.

Comment: Sorry but that's just wrong. See Takkat's Answer.

Comment: @Eugene Seidel: I typed resonieren into Google Translate for a German-English translation, and it gave me "resonate," which is what I suspected. Now Takkat changed the form of the word to räsonieren and drew his own conclusions from that change. But I didn't make a change from O.P.'s "resonieren."

Comment: You wouldn't have made that mistake if you could guess at the meaning of the CH-German quote: "Do goht de Meischter sälber us, und foht a resonniere." My translation (it may not be 100% accurate but it will be close enough): DE-German: Da geht der Meister selbst hinaus und fängt an zu räsonieren. English: And now the master himself is going out and starting on one of his rants.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel: Yes, the master could be "ranting." He could also be "responding" (resonating) to something Hundli, Birli, Joggeli, Chamblis, or the others said or did. It's even possible that "resonieren" means "ranting" in this context. But Google Translate tells me that it means "resonate" generally.

Comment: "resonating" is not "responding". Apologies but I thought that the purpose of SE was for "experts" (= people who know what they are talking about) to handle competently questions from people seeking advice; and I don't see the ability to use Google Translate as sufficient. So -1 from me. And while I'm at it, I'll change my rough translation to: "And now the master himself is going out and scolding them." This scolding finally does the trick: the butcher will slaughter the calf, the calf will drink the water, and so on. That this is impossible is why kids love the song!

Comment: @EugeneSeidel: Please see my question on meta.http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/388/is-a-general-response-an-acceptable-answer-to-a-specific-question Depending on the general response, I may withdraw my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3205/discussion-between-tom-au-and-eugene-seidel)

Comment: _Birli_, in any case, is not a person. Birli are the pears that the master sends Joggeli to shake out of the pear tree :)

Comment: “resonieren“ is a word used in physics and music (the [Duden is with me here](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/resonieren)). I cannot imagine any case where it would mean “respond”. And although I don't know the song I can't imagine anything like “der Meister fängt an mitzuschwingen” (=zu resonieren) could be meant...

Comment: @Clemens: "Respond" was a bad translation on my part. But if you clap your hands, and I do the same, I am "resonating." Likewise for, say different parts of a bridge or a musical instrument. That's the meaning I took for the word. The other English word I would use is "copycatting." I didn't even claim my definition was right, just that it was the one I WOULD USE.

Comment: I disagree that to people clapping hands at the same time are resonating. But besides that: in the quote given it is not very probable that “resonieren” is meant. It is very likely spelt this way to mimick the Swiss dialect, just the way “sälber” (=selber) and “foht” (=fängt) are...